# Choose the correct version of etcd backup in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I want to create a snapshot of the etcd instance. The etcd instance is running etcd version 3.3.10. I used `ETCDCTL_API=3` in the following command:

```sh
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl 
--endpoints https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 
--cacert /opt/ca.crt 
--cert /opt/etcd-client.crt 
--key=/opt/etcd-client.key 
  snapshot save > /var/lib/backup/etcd-snapshot.db
```

Which version of ETCDCTL_API should I use? Should I use the highest version?

Comment: The one you are using is absolutely fine. go ahead !!

Comment: Yes, what's wrong with that line? 

Comment: I did not know if I should use ETCDCTL_API=3 or ETCDCTL_API=3.3.10 but I already know it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`etcdctl snapshot save /path/file_name.db`" command works only when the api version is set to 3

```
export ETCDCTL_API=3
```

there no option available in api version 2 to run the command with the snapshot save option.